# How to log the result of a select query in tMysqlRow to tLogRow in Talend?

Tags: mysql, talend

I have a simple job with two components tMysqlRow connected via Row/Main to tLogRow.

I have a simple select statement in the tMysqlRow component that I have tested directly on the db and it works and returns a single record.  When I run the job it says "1 rows in 0.04s" so I assume that means that the tMysqlRow component is getting 1 row from the db.

In the tLogRow component I have pressed the "Sync columns" button on the basic tab and when I edit the schema I can see all the columns are there.

But when I run the job, it logs the following:

```
Starting job LoadContextVariablesFromDBRecordDemo at 13:07 30/09/2015.
[statistics] connecting to socket on port 3714
[statistics] connected

||||||

[statistics] disconnected
Job LoadContextVariablesFromDBRecordDemo ended at 13:07 30/09/2015. [exit code=0]
```

So I am at a loss for why the values are not logged?

What am I doing wrong here?

Regards,

Scott

Comment: Try to run your job using debug mode and see if there is data in the output link of tMysqlRow.

Answer (score 2):

So I got some advise from the talend forum telling me:

> Do you really need to use tMysqlRow component? From what I understand,
>   tMysqlInput is just the component you need. It directly returns the
>   result of the query and propagates it into the flow. tMysqlRow
>   component does not handle the returned data by default. In case you
>   are restricted to use the tMysqlRow component, you have to check the
>   Propagate QUERY's recordset in the Advanced settings of tMysqlRow
>   component and then use the tParseRecordSet component to extract the
>   data. For more information and guide, please, refer to the tMysqlRow
>   Component Guide page. There is also an example on how to do this.

[URL to the forum post](https://www.talendforge.org/forum/viewtopic.php?pid=170000)

I had another issue after this was solved where the tMysqlInput component show a warning message:

> the schema's dbType is not correct for this component

This was also solved in that same thread.

Regards,

Scott